# bash to pass array to ssh to another server

Tags: bash

In the below `bash` I am trying to pass the `${array[$i]}` to `ssh` after changing to a specific directory, but `${array[$i]}` it is not recognized? The goal is to use the id in `${array[$i]}` (there may be more than 1) to further go into that directory. The `bash` seems to work as expected except for the `${array[$i]}` not be passed.

**bash**

```
readarray -t array <<< "$(printf '%s\n' $id)"
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )) ; do
   echo "${array[$i]}"
done

 sshpass -f file.txt ssh -o strictHostKeyChecking=no -t xxx@xxx "${array[$i]}" 'cd path/to/folder/"$array[$i]" && exec bash -l'
 echo ${array[$i]}
```

**maybe?**

```
readarray -t array <<< "$(printf '%s\n' $id)"
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )) ; do
   echo "${array[$i]}"
done

 for i in "${array[$i]} ; do
 sshpass -f file.txt ssh -o strictHostKeyChecking=no -t xxx@xxx "${array[$i]}" 'cd path/to/folder && exec bash -l'
done
```

**contents of array[$i]**   ---- array[$i] will be different in number each time but the format will always be the same ----

```
00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx
00-0001-yyy-yyy-yyy
```

**desired ssh**

```
cd path/to/folder/00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx && cp *.txt* /home/location
cd path/to/folder/00-0000-yyy-yyy-yyy && cp *.txt* /home/location
```

Comment: As  a future note, `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"` is a much easier way to print all array contents one-line-to-an-item.

Comment: That said, because array contents *can contain literal newlines*, the above isn't a safe serialization format; only NULs aren't allowed to be present inside elements (which is why they're what you should use).

Comment: Anyhow, I don't know how/why you expect the above code to work, or even what "working" means in its context -- the `sshpass` command isn't in a loop at all, f/e; and when you pass multiple arguments to ssh, they're just concatenated together into a single shell command.

Comment: ...so, when you pass `"${array[$i]}"` as an extra argument: (1) what kind of thing do you expect it to contain? (2) how, and why, do you expect the remote shell to parse that opaque thing you aren't showing us in any particular way?

Comment: so are you saying that `${array[$i]` needs to be passed to `sshpass` in a loop? I will edit the post as well. Thank you :).

Comment: I'm not saying that, because I don't understand what you're actually trying to do, so I can't say anything useful and specific (and afaict, neither can anyone else). Do you want *only one* ssh connection to happen passing *all* the array elements across at the same time? Do you want one connection per element? ...?

Comment: Yes, each element in `$array[$i]` is an id on a newline, that after `ssh` will be used to `cd` to. I will add this to the post.  Thank you :).

Comment: It's still not clear. Do you want *one* copy of ssh to `cd` into a series of directories (and do nothing else when in them, but just `cd` to the next one?); One copy per directory (doing what when there?); something else?

Comment: one copy of `ssh` will `cd` in a series of directories. In each directory there are specific files `*.txt*` that will be `cp` to a location ( /home/location). Thank you :).

Comment: Thank you -- I think that's enough to allow a useful answer now; I've edited mine to be directly on-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we generate a single remote that runs `(cd ... && exec cp)` for each array element, with each in a subshell to prevent the `cd` from having side effects on subsequent elements' commands:

```
printf -v cmd_q '(cd /path/to/folder/%q && exec cp -- *.txt* /home/location)\n' "${array[@]}"
sshpass -f file.txt ssh -o strictHostKeyChecking=no -t xxx@xxx "$cmd_q"
```

The `exec` is a minor performance enhancement, consuming the subshell started with the parenthesis by replacing it with the `cp` process.

The `%q` placeholder in the `printf` format string gets substituted with the individual array values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation :)